# How can I make my capturing link matcher "lazy"?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In ECMAScript, and here's my regex that i'm working with:

```
replace(/\[(.+)\s+->\s+([^\]]+)]/g, '<a class=adl_btnlnk href="$2">$1</a>');
```

That's fine for the following string:

```
"[INNER\"',';!@#$%^&*gobbeldygook ->    -> -> http://li.nk?u=r&l]"
```

...It does exactly what I need.  But what about when I have:

```
"[INNER\"',';!@#$%^&*gobbeldygook ->    -> -> http://li.nk?u=r&l] laksjfalksdjf98723&*(*&(*@&#$ [foo -> http://li.nk]"
```

It results in one, broken, link:

```
"<a class=adl_btnlnk href="http://li.nk">INNER"',';!@#$%^&*gobbeldygook ->    -> -> http://li.nk?u=r&l] laksjfalksdjf98723&*(*&(*@&#$ [foo</a>"
```

How can I make it into:

```
"<a class=adl_btnlnk href="http://li.nk?u=r&l">INNER"',';!@#$%^&*gobbeldygook ->    -></a> laksjfalksdjf98723&*(*&(*@&#$ <a class=adl_btnlink href="http://li.nk">foo</a>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `+` quantifiers take as less as possible by appending a `?`. But you have to alter your regexp a bit so that it takes as much as possible excluding `]` characters for the first group. Also, the last group shouldn't include the arrows:

```
/\[([^\]]+?)\s+->\s+([^->\]]+?)]/g
```

Comment: The ones after my `\s`s or the one following `]`?

Comment: @adlwalrus: Posted the actual regexp.

Comment: oh yes, i usually try to do that.  Just forgot -- sorry :?